# How to let two ASP.NET Web Api both available at one website hosted in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

There are two Web APIs in my project, one for IOS, anohter for Android. Both of the Web APIs shares the same Bill & Dal.

Route of Web API for IOS is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/ios/{controller}/...

And for Android, it ts xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/android/{controller}/...

But when I published the project (Hosted in IIS), I found that only the API of IOScan be accessed. If I access Android's Api, the HTTP status code is 404.

So, how to config so that both of the Web Api can be available in IIS?
[image]

Comment: You'll have to give each a different application name `domain.com/ios-app/` and `domain.com/android-app/` then create two applications under the site node.

Comment: Not sure if I understood properly. How about adding a path in `web.config`?